# Laradock changing php-fpm version inside workspace

Tags: php, docker, laravel-5, laradock

I am not able to change the php-fpm version inside the workspace. I'm trying to install PHP version 7.1
My docker version is

```
 Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

Every time it installs PHP version

```
PHP 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 08:53:57) ( NTS )
```

My dockerfile inside workspace looks like as follows:

```
ARG LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=7.1

FROM laradock/workspace:2.2-${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

ARG LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION

# Set Environment Variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Start as root
USER root

###########################################################################
# Laradock non-root user:
###########################################################################

# Add a non-root user to prevent files being created with root permissions on host machine.
ARG PUID=1000
ENV PUID ${PUID}
ARG PGID=1000
ENV PGID ${PGID}
```

Comment: Why are you changing the docker file? you can change your php version at .env file.

Comment: I tried and It din't pick the changes from there.

Answer (score 5):

#### change PHP_VERSION in .env file

#### Build fpm and cli for new version

```
docker-compose build php-fpm                       
docker-compose build workspace
```

#### Restart Container to use new version of php

```
docker-compose down                       
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql workspace redis
```

Comment: Hello Ossy, welcome to StackOverflow! You could increase the readability of your answer by using code blocks for the `docker-compose` commands. The content of your answer is great, keep going!

Answer (score 1):

- Change the value in .env only.
- Rebuild the containers with --no-cache

  ```
  docker-compose down
  docker-compose build --no-cache php-fpm
  docker-compose build --no-cache workspace
  docker-compose up -d phpmyadmin workspace php-fpm nginx mysql maildev redis redis-webui #dockup
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine after add ``--no-cache`` option